# How to fill empty space in a JToolbar

Tags: java, swing

I have a **JToolbar** in one of my panels.

**Abridged Code:**

```
//for the containing panel
panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());


//adding the toolbar
panel.add(toolbar, BorderLayout.WEST);
```

The toolbar has two `JButton`s that I add using `GridBagLayout` to make them of equal width

//code for the toolbar

```
toolbar=new JToolbar();
toolbar.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
btn1 = new JBUtton("update layout");
btn2 = new JButton("exit!");
GridBagContraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.gridx=0;
gbc.gridy=1;
gbc.fill = GridBagConstrainsts.HORIZONTAL;
toolbar.add(btn1,gbc);
gbc.gridy=1;
toolbar.add(btn1,gbc);
```

This code renders a vertical toolbar with button that take equal width. The only problem is that the height of the toolbar is more than the height of the buttons and hence this code renders the buttons in the vertical center of the toolbar. Instead I would want that the buttons are aligned to the top such that all the empty space is added to the end of the toolbar.

Now:

```
 ----------
 |        |
 ----------
 |  btn   |
 ----------
 |  btn2  |
 ----------
 |        |
 ----------
```

What I want

```
 ----------
 |   btn  |
 ----------
 |   btn2 |
 ----------
 |        |
 ----------
 |        |
 ----------
```

Comment: I would think that the behavior you desire is the default behavior for JToolBars, and if I remember correctly, you shouldn't have to give the JToolBar a layout manager.

Comment: I agree with @HovercraftFullOfEels - if you're really stuck on using a GridBagLayout, though, you should add `gbc.weighty = 1` before you add `btn2`, you will also need to supply `gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH`, but this will mean that your toolbar will only ever be used in the vertical position

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes, it will always be there in the Vertical position. On a later though, my toolbar is no different than a panel. I will try your suggestion

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I am using the GridBagLayout for just getting the buttons to be of equal width. I don't really need it if I knew better ways of getting the buttons to be of equal width. Basically, I suck at Swing :P

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can just add a `Box.createVerticalGlue()` to the toolbar, without changing the layout to GridBagLayout.  That will fill up the remaining space after the buttons and push them to the top.

Comment: but then I won't get the two buttons with same width as in GridBagLayout

Comment: Hmm.  I guess not.  (Sorry)  Well, put the "glue" in the bottom of your panel that uses GridBagLayout to fill up the extra space, or just set the GridBagConstraints as MadProgrammer suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Feels a bit like resurrecting a dead. But I had a very similar issue and found a solution, so why not sharing it:

You have to set a maximum size to the buttons, otherwise maximum size is calculated by the ButtonUI. And setHorizontalAlignment to SwingConstants.RIGHT to get the button content aligned:

```
public class JToolBarPractise extends JFrame {

  public JToolBarPractise() {
    super();
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
        System.exit(0);
      }
    });
    JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar(SwingConstants.VERTICAL);
    JButton button1 = new JButton("Update Layout!");
    button1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    button1.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Short.MAX_VALUE, button1.getPreferredSize().height));
    toolBar.add(button1);
    JButton button2 = new JButton("Exit!");
    button2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    button2.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Short.MAX_VALUE, button2.getPreferredSize().height));
    button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        System.exit(0);
      }
    });
    toolBar.add(button2);
    contentPanel.add(toolBar, BorderLayout.WEST);
    getContentPane().add(contentPanel);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException,
    IllegalAccessException, UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
    JToolBarPractise main = new JToolBarPractise();
    main.setSize(300, 300);
    main.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```